# will updating on base tables changes the table in linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I have a SQL Server1 holding a DB1 which contains Table1. And on Server1, I have a linked server (named LinkedServer2) pointing to Server2 (with DB2 which contains Table2).

Now if I do some changes in Table2 on Server2, will the change be presented automatically on LinkedServer2? Or I need to do some synchronization work?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself and see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Linked server is just a connection to the server that it references - it is not some form of cached data from the original server. At least part of every query run against a linked server is actually run on the logical server referenced by the link, specifically to retrieve the data referenced in the query.

TL;DR:  Yes, the data changes will show up automatically.